# editing the bash file

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, bash

I was using ubuntu 12.04.I have added the following line to both my bashrc file and bash_profile.
The bash-profile file is created by me in order to add the lines

```
export CUDA_INSTALL_PATH="/opt/cuda"
export PATH="${CUDA_INSTALL_PATH}/bin:${PATH}"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/cuda/lib:/opt/cuda/lib64
```

Now when I open terminal it was showing

```
bash: export: `/opt/cuda': not a valid identifier
```

What was the problem. What should be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space after the `=`.  Get rid of it, you want no spaces on either side of it.